# yii CGridView initial sort

Tags: sorting, yii, cgridview

Is there any way to set an initial sorting a CGridView?
I have a DB table that contains: id | name | description | create_time...
In my CGridView I want my data to be shown without the id (this can be done by setting columns in CGridView but I would like to know if there is any other method to eliminate this fields from dataProvider) and I want to have my data sorted after name ASC. How can I do this because  it always sort after id and I can't set a criteria for CGridView?

Comment: CGridView only displays the sorted data. You have to sort in in your query (usually a `CActiveDataProvider`). If you've used Gii for scaffolding, your model's `search` method is where the query is. There's an example here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a default order in your model respectively the `CActiveDataProvider`. The following snippet sorts by the column `SortMeColumn` by default.

```
public function search()
{
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->compare('ID', $this->ID, true);
  $criteria->compare('SortMeColumn', $this->SortMeColumn, true);

  return new CActiveDataProvider($this,
        array(
           'criteria' => $criteria,
           'sort' => array(
              'defaultOrder' => array(
                 'SortMeColumn' => CSort::SORT_DESC
              ),
           ),
        ));
}
```

See [CSort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#defaultOrder-detail) for reference.

Comment: A very good answer. But what should I do in the case that I do not always want to use this order as a default order? What should I do in the case that I have another page which requires default sorting after ID?

Comment: @tzortzik: in this case pass the `array` for `defaultOrder` as a parameter in any way you like.

Comment: I think this mean overloading the search function as `public function search($arrDefaultOrder)`